# No header files found while trying to use luarocks

Tags: lua, luarocks

I am willing to install lua and luarocks to install additional packages, but so far, it didn't work. This is what I did:

- Download lua54 binaries
- Download luarocks binaries, and specify the directory for lua

When making the first attempts, I got the error:

```
cannot find header files
```

But there was no header files with the lua binary, so I just added source file into the same directory, and now I get:

```
lua version of header files are different
```

But both have the same version, 5.4

Any idea how to get luarocks working, I am on windows.